# Mouse Frezzing ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04

Tags: drivers, ati, mouse

I have tried multiple reinstalls of the OS. Multiple drives tried AMD video card drivers and X server drivers nothing works more then 5 mins then mouse freezes all over again. System has HD Radian 6570 video card 24 gigs ram  4440 I5 CPU quad core. Tried Ubuntu 15.04 also dropped back to 14.04 I have looked for erros in system logs and can find none. One strange thing is (and could be totally unrelated) System monitor says CPU is 80% but nothing is showing more then 11% in under tab resources. It cant be lack of ram GPU  or CPU. Gpointer also don’t work. I’m new to Linux.[driver page as reqested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg7NP.png)

Comment: Please use some basic interpunctuation in your post.

Comment: 1) format your question; 2) avoid chit-chat (we know you are not dumb)  :=| ; 3) don't explain how the mice broke...  yr window ... trying to escape ... (really !!!?) 4) etc... And we'll take it from there. AU can help you; just don't make it so difficult. We have jobs too.

Comment: BTW, please show us the Graphics drivers you have available (screen capture of your `Ubuntu Software Center > Edit menu> Software Sources submenu > Additional Drivers tab`). Place the png or jpg file in your original post by editing it and pasting the image. This has all the aspect of Graphic card incompatibility or missing driver problem.

Comment: Ok I wanted to thank you i solved it i found a mini dongle for an old mouse that was same brand for some reason it must have been confusing the current mouse as when i removed it the problem went away and hasn’t returned in over 2 weeks.